# Django Templates: Accessing FK methods

Tags: django, templates, foreign-key-relationship

Good Afternoon,

I'd like to be able to display a returned value from a method that is in a foreign table (the template obj shares a one-many relationship):

```
models.py

class teacher(stuff):
    name = models.charfield()
    website = models.URLField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, db_index=True, unique=True)

    def get_page_url(self):
        return reverse('teacher_page', args=[self.slug])


class homework(stuff):
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(teacher)
    due_date = models.DateField()
    other assignment stuff..
```

I pass the assignment object into my template, and can access it's attributes like so:

```
{{homework.due_date}}
```

but let us say I want to display the page of the teacher who has assigned the homework. I thought I should be able to access it like so:

```
<a href='{{homework.teacher_set.get_page_url}}'>teacher page</a>
```

But this just results in an attribute error.

How can I get the url?

NOTE: This example was written on the fly for the purpose of conveying the question only. No syntax trolls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a forward relationship, you would just do

```
{{homework.assignment.get_page_url}}
```

Further, if you are looking for a reverse foreign key relationship, you would do

```
{{teacher.name}}

{% for homework in teacher.homework_set.all %}
    {{homework.due_date}}
{% endfor %}
```

because `teacher.homework_set` [returns a `Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried this, and many different permutations of this, and I couldn't get the attributes to show. However, I took your advice to leave out the _set, since this is a forward relationship. When I tried "{{homework.assignment.get_page_url}}", it worked. So using the foreign model name didn't yield anything, but using the field to which the FK was defined did. Should this be the case?

Comment: I made a typo. For forward relationships, you would use the field name directly. For reverse relationships, you would use the lowercase model name followed by `_set` if you have not specified a `related_name` attribute.